# Chef recipe: can't capture output from backticks to variable in ruby_block

Tags: ruby, output, chef-infra, backticks

I have a Chef recipe with a ruby_block containing this:

```
myoutput = `keytool -import -alias #{al} -keystore #{ks} -storepass #{pw} -file #{ca} -trustcacerts -noprompt`
puts ":" + myoutput + ":"
Chef::Log.error('Error installing CA Cert') unless myoutput.include? "Certificate was added to keystore"
```

(All of the variables are properly set.)  Here's the relevant output:

```
Certificate was added to keystore
::
[2013-07-03T21:26:41-07:00] ERROR: Error installing CA Cert
```

Notice the ::. Why isn't myoutput being set correctly?  When I run that command by hand, I get the expected output.  The command in the backticks does what it's supposed to, so I know it's running, but for some reason the standard output from the command is not getting assigned to myoutput and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?  Thanks -- Dave

Edit: the reason is because the output of this particular 'keytool' invocation is going to stderr, not stdout.

Comment: use double-quotes to get your variable interpreted young padawan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be that the output is directed to STDERR instead of STDOUT. Try this:

```rb
myoutput = `keytool -import -alias #{al} -keystore #{ks} -storepass #{pw} -file #{ca} -trustcacerts -noprompt 2>&1`
```

I don't have any certificate to import to test this, but running `` `keytool` `` alone sends output to STDERR, whereas `` `keytool 2>&1` `` works fine. So I'm guessing this application writes to STDERR normally (very odd).

Comment: That is exactly the reason!  That is unusual behavior but I confirmed it here.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

#### 2016 Update

You could do

```rb
require 'mixlib/shellout'
cmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("keytool -import -alias #{al} -keystore #{ks} -storepass #{pw} -file #{ca} -trustcacerts -noprompt")
cmd.run_command
# you can now use cmd.stdout and cmd.stderr
```

The chef documentation now indicates that **you should not use backticks** but the `mixlib-shellout` library:

> Always use mixlib-shellout to shell out. Never use backticks, Process.spawn, popen4, or anything else!
>
> The mixlib-shellout module provides a simplified interface to shelling out while still collecting both standard out and standard error and providing full control over environment, working directory, uid, gid, etc.

See [this part of the doc](https://docs.chef.io/ruby.html#shelling-out) for more details.